# Android TabLayout not displaying text but displaying icon only

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I need your help. I followed this sample [here](https://github.com/natuan241/Android-Design-Support-Library-Sample/tree/master/AndroidDesignTabLayout)

All is working except text is not displayed only the icon.

here's my code:

**MainActivity.class**

```
  private int[] ICONS = {
        R.drawable.tab_icon_home, R.drawable.tab_icon_heart,
        R.drawable.tab_icon_news, R.drawable.tab_icon_profile
};

private final String[] TITLES = {"Home", "Shortlist", "Feed" , "Profile"};

ViewPager mViewpager;
TabLayout mTabs;
private FragmentPageAdapter pageAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    setupViewPager(mViewpager);
    setupTabLayout(mTabs);

}

public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    pageAdapter = new FragmentPageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
    pageAdapter.addFragment(CardFragment.getInstance(TITLES[0]), TITLES[0], ICONS[0]);
    pageAdapter.addFragment(CardFragment.getInstance(TITLES[1]), TITLES[1], ICONS[1]);
    pageAdapter.addFragment(CardFragment.getInstance(TITLES[2]), TITLES[2], ICONS[2]);
    pageAdapter.addFragment(CardFragment.getInstance(TITLES[3]), TITLES[3], ICONS[3]);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
}

public void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);


    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(TITLES[i]);
        tab.setCustomView(pageAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
    tabLayout.requestFocus();
}
```

**xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadowView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:rotation="180" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:background="@color/white"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**CardFragment.class:**

```
public static CardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    CardFragment f = new CardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

public static CardFragment getInstance(String message) {
    CardFragment mainFragment = new CardFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("MSG", message);
    mainFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return mainFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card,container,false);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);
    return rootView;
}
```

What do you think is missing in my code? I'm stuck and don't know how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show `CardFragment` class code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I've added it. Pls. check thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As in provide code link, also calling `setText` method for setting title for current Fragment.

Also currently getting Fragment instance by calling String version of `getInstance`, so use getString for getting title in `onCreateView` :

```
...
ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);
TextView textTitle=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.<textview_id>);
textTitle.setText(""+ getArguments().getString("Bundle"));
return rootView;
```